# Help! jQuery not loading on iPhone

Tags: iphone, jquery, mobile-safari

Hey CodeWarriors, anyone know if on the iPhone in Mobile Safari whether there is a timeout for loading a certain amount of Javascripting/jQuery?? The moving background and the black covering over the heart are not working on the iPhone, but are solid on Firefox and my MacBook Pro's Safari – they don't load:

http://www.zookeeper.com/beyourowncreature/2011

Still working on some things on this site before it launches...

Thanks in advance if you have any ideas.

-Dave

Comment: I see a parse and syntax error in Safari. The iPhone has a Safari developer toggle in the Settings app that you can use to get error messages on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

All I can see is an error in your jquery.spritely on line 268, 1st line in the window.Touch clause. el[0] does not exist

```
    activeOnClick: function() {
        // make this the active script if clicked...
        var el = $(this);
        if (window.Touch) { // iphone method see http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone/9 or http://www.nimblekit.com/tutorials.html for clues...
            el[0].ontouchstart = function(e) {
                $._spritely.activeSprite = el;
            };
        } else {
            el.click(function(e) {
                $._spritely.activeSprite = el;
            });
        }
        return this;
    },
```

And as the previous comment says, you have and unmatched  tag

Comment: Hi Ceejayoz and Jamgold, THANK YOU very much for your responses. They helped to solve the problem and this is now firing correctly. GREATLY appreciate you taking the time.